# jquery touchwipe how to get $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, mobile, touch

I am using the jquery touchwipe plugin on my scroll list, and i can't get
attribute from $(this).I want to use $(this) to get its children elment class="t7 edit" and add class 'show' to it.Does anyone know how to fix it?

html:

```
                <div id="main_list_wrapper">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="t7 edit"></div>
                        <div class="t8 cancel"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="t7 edit"></div>
                        <div class="t8 cancel"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="t7 edit"></div>
                        <div class="t8 cancel"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="t7 edit"></div>
                        <div class="t8 cancel"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="t7 edit"></div>
                        <div class="t8 cancel"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

script code:

```
var $main_list_wrapper = $("#main_list_wrapper").find('.item');

$main_list_wrapper.touchwipe({
    preventDefaultEvents: false,
    wipeLeft: function() { 
        $(this).find('.t8.cancel').removeClass('show');
        $(this).find('.t7.edit').removeClass('show');
        var thisclass = $(this).attr('class');
        alert(thisclass);
        return false;
    },
    wipeRight: function() { 
        $sb(this).find('.t8.cancel').addClass('show');
        $sb(this).find('.t7.edit').addClass('show');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Like alert(thisclass). It shows "undefine".

---

Thank you all.my friend write this to me, and it work!

```
$main_list_wrapper.each(function () {
    var $this = $sb(this);

    $this.touchwipe({
        preventDefaultEvents: false,
        wipeLeft: function() { 
            var $pcs = $this;
            $pcs.find('.t8').removeClass('show');
            $pcs.find('.t7').removeClass('show');
            return false;
        },
        wipeRight: function() { 
            var $pcs = $this;
            $pcs.find('.t8').addClass('show');
            $pcs.find('.t7').addClass('show');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'i can't get anything about $(this)' ? please elaborate. if you're asking what `$(this)` is, i think in this case it would be $main_list_wrapper.

Comment: I want to use $(this) to get its children elment class="t7 edit" and add class 'show' to it.Thank you.

Comment: `this` may be referring to the function `wipeLeft()`?

Comment: I came across this post and thanks to your friend who wrote the above I have managed to get my swipe to work! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$("#main_list_wrapper")` is `NULL`. Make sure that this snippet of code is located in your JQuery onLoad: `$(document).ready(function () { /* CODE */ });`

`find()` takes a list of class names delimited by commas.
Change: `$(this).find('.t8.cancel')` to this:`$(this).find('.t8, .cancel')`

Comment: Yes,this snippet of code is located in my JQuery onLoad: $(document).ready(function() { /* CODE */ });The biggest problem is i can't get attribute from $(this) or to get its child elment.thank you.

Comment: Well, @dunli stated earlier that the touchwipe wraps an object. You may only need native Javascript to access this inner object: `var element = document.getElementById('main_list_wrapper').children[0];` This may also work if you want to stick to JQuery: `element.children(":first");`

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` refers to the object the `function()` belongs to, it is not referring to your `$main_list_wrapper`.
Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4700899/1953933)
You can just use `$main_list_wrapper.find('.t8.cancel').removeClass('show');` instead.