# Hi, I don't understand how 'this' keyword in bind method works in this code

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;

}


Person.prototype.myFriends5 = function(friends) {
  var arr = friends.map(function(el) {
    return this.name + ' is friends with ' + el;
  }.bind(this)); 
  console.log(arr); 
}

var friends = ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Mark']
new Person('John').myFriends5(friends);
```

Hi, I am having a problem to understand how 'this' keyword works in bind method.
So the result of the code above is this "John is friends with Bob","John is friends with Jane","John is friends with Mark". 
 But without .bind(this), the result comes out like this " is friends with Bob"," is friends with Jane"," is friends with Mark".
What is the difference with and without .bind(this) in this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

You correctly observed that .bind(this) makes "this" available in your code, mainly because you're inside a "map" loop function. Here's an example of how you can make "this" available easily: ['this' in function inside prototype function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700880/this-in-function-inside-prototype-function)

Additional: If you look at ES6 classes, they now have a constructor and the `class` keyword and you don't need to use `prototype`.

[es6 classes docs](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/)

excerpt:

```
class Polygon {
  // ..and an (optional) custom class constructor. If one is
  // not supplied, a default constructor is used instead:
  // constructor() { }
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.name = 'Polygon';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  sayName() {
    ChromeSamples.log('Hi, I am a ', this.name + '.');
  }
}
```

So if you look at above example, it makes it a bit clearer to look at how the JavaScript class works and it's more like PHP or Java.

Mozilla developer network documentation:

[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: If you want to provide an alternative to `bind`, why not suggesting to use fat arrows functions?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: with `bind` you tell the function bound, what the keyword `this` should be inside of it.

**Example for better understanding**

```js
var test = function(x) {
  console.log(this.some_important_thing);
  console.log(x);
}

var test_obj = {
  some_important_thing: "Wazaaaa :D"
};

var test2 = test.bind(test_obj, "A"); // new function with prefilled this and parameter
test2();

var test3 = test.bind(test_obj); // new function with prefilled this
test3("B");
```